# how to draw the Bar Graph in Android Programatically?

Tags: android

can any body hep drawing the bar graph in android according to the data on x and y axis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[charts4j](http://code.google.com/p/charts4j/) Is another good chart API. It uses the Google charts server to generate the charts and returns them to you as an image.

Answer (score 4):

I think this librairy can help you : [achartengine](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/)

Answer (score 3):

I've successfully used [AndroidPlot](http://androidplot.com) in the past for doing line graphs, but they also support bar graphs.  You could give that a shot.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public class BarchartsampleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    static XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset;
    static XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer;
    static XYSeriesRenderer rendererSeries;
    static CategorySeries series;
    static GraphicalView mChartView;
    String xvalstring1,xvalstring2,xvalstring3,xvalstring4,xvalstring5;
    int xvalint1,xvalint2,xvalint3,xvalint4,xvalint5;


     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        xvalstring1=intent.getStringExtra("xvalstring1").toString().trim();
        xvalstring2=intent.getStringExtra("xvalstring2").toString().trim();
        xvalstring3=intent.getStringExtra("xvalstring3").toString().trim();
        xvalstring4=intent.getStringExtra("xvalstring4").toString().trim();
        xvalstring5=intent.getStringExtra("xvalstring5").toString().trim();     
        xvalint1=Integer.parseInt(xvalstring1);
        xvalint2=Integer.parseInt(xvalstring2);
        xvalint3=Integer.parseInt(xvalstring3);
        xvalint4=Integer.parseInt(xvalstring4);
        xvalint5=Integer.parseInt(xvalstring5);

     String[] titles = new String[] { "USER INPUTS" };
        List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
        x.add(new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
        List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
        values
                .add(new double[] { xvalint1,xvalint2,xvalint3,xvalint4,xvalint5 });
        dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setChartTitle("USER INPUTS");
        renderer.setXTitle("X");
        renderer.setYTitle("Y");
        renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        renderer.setXAxisMin(0);
        renderer.setXAxisMax(10);
        renderer.setYAxisMin(0);
        renderer.setYAxisMax(40);
        renderer.setClickEnabled(false);
        renderer.setExternalZoomEnabled(false);
        renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        renderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { 0,5,0,100 });
        renderer.setZoomLimits(new double[] { -10, 20, -10, 40 });
        renderer.setShowGrid(true);
        /*renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
        renderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);*/
        renderer.setBarSpacing(1.5);
        renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLUE);
        renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
        renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
        renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        renderer.setMargins(new int[] {20, 30, 15, 20});
        renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.GREEN);
        rendererSeries = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        rendererSeries.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        rendererSeries.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(rendererSeries);

      if (mChartView == null) {
            Log.d("Oncreate ", "if (mChartView == null)");
            mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(this, mDataset(titles,
                    x, values), renderer, Type.DEFAULT);
            layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        } else {
//          mChartView.repaint();
            Log.d("Oncreate ", "if (mChartView != null)");
        }
    }    
    private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset(String[] titles,
            List<double[]> xValues, List<double[]> yValues) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset1 = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        addXYSeries(dataset1, titles, xValues, yValues, 0);
        return dataset1;
    }
    private void addXYSeries(XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset, String[] titles,
            List<double[]> xValues, List<double[]> yValues, int scale) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int length = titles.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            XYSeries series = new XYSeries(titles[i], scale);
            double[] xV = xValues.get(i);
            double[] yV = yValues.get(i);
            int seriesLength = xV.length;
            for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) {
                series.add(xV[k], yV[k]);



            }
            dataset.addSeries(series);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: a little explanation may be useful to help people understand this code