# How to show fusion charts in android 2.3.3 devices

Tags: android, fusioncharts

I am developing an application which requires fusion chart integration with android. Fusion chart is working absolutely fine with API level 3 above but it is not working on 2.3.3 devices. 
Screen blinking is there then nothing happens. Please provide a solution for my problem.
If anyone have any sought of sample code then please share it. It will be a great help.

Edited:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView mWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    mWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWeb.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWeb.loadDataWithBaseURL("", getHTML(), "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
}

private String getHTML() {
    String html = "<html><head><script language=\"JavaScript\"src=\"file:///android_asset/FusionCharts.js\"></script></head><body bgcolor=\"#ffffff\"><div id=\"chartdiv\" align=\"center\">The chart will appear within this DIV. This text will be replaced by the chart.</div><script type=\"text/javascript\">FusionCharts.setCurrentRenderer(\"javascript\");var myChart = new FusionCharts(\"file:///android_asset/Column3D.swf\", \"myChartId\", \"400\",\"400\");myChart.setXMLData(\"<graph caption='Title' decimalPrecision='0' formatNumberScale='0' showNames='1' xAxisName='XData' yAxisName='YData' ><set name='One' value='120' color='456553' /><set name='Two' value='345' color='234567' /><set name='Three' value='565' color='098765' /></graph>\");myChart.render(\"chartdiv\");</script></body></html>";
    return html;

}
```

}

Comment: put share your code here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the fusion charts are not supported below the Android v. 3.x, as mentioned by one of their staff in this [forum](http://forum.fusioncharts.com/topic/8012-fusion-charts-on-android/) on fusioncharts.com.

You may refer to some other chart engines or try this [example](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/bar-chart-in-android-with-out-any-built-in-jars/) for implementing chart without using any external jar file. Or you may refer these replies for similar chart engines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768372/how-to-draw-the-bar-graph-in-android-programatically) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976931/complete-bar-chart-in-screen-in-achartengine).

I personally have used AchartEngine and you may refer to this [tutorial](http://www.truiton.com/2013/04/android-tutorial-drawing-achartengine-bar-chart-with-example/) on how to implement it.